# I'm not able to keep logged in in Django

Tags: python, django

Whenever I login using the login(request, user) it works but after redirecting to a different it goes back to being anonymous user. I use a custom authentication backend and I don't know why this happens. I have a mysql database with existing data and this only happens to the old data and the new one works fine....

Here's my login view...

```
def trc_login(request):
# try:
    context_dict = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        if (len(email) < 30):
            username = email
        else:
            username = email.split("@")[0]

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print user
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            print request.user # prints the user
            return HttpResponse("success")
        else:
            context_dict['message'] = "Wrong credentials"
            return HttpResponse("invalid details")
    else:
        return render(request, 'general/login.html', context_dict)
```

This is my backend

```
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
    try:
        pwd = hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()
        user = USER.objects.get(email=username)
        django_user = None

        if pwd == user.user_password:
            # if (len(user.email) < 30):
            #     username = user.email
            # else:
            #     username = user.email.split("@")[0]

            try:
                if is_email(username):
                    try:
                        django_user = User.objects.filter(email=username)[0]
                        # pdb.set_trace()
                    except User.DoesNotExist:
                        return None
                else:
                    #We have a non-email address username we should try username
                    try:
                        django_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                    except User.DoesNotExist:
                        return None
                # if django_user.check_password(password):
                #   return django_user
            except Exception, e:
                print e
            # django_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            return django_user
        else:
            return None
    except USER.DoesNotExist:
        return None

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return USER.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except USER.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

This is my models part....

```
class USER(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  #             Field name made lowercase.
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=85L, db_column=u'EMAIL')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=16L, db_column=u'FIRST_NAME')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=16L, db_column=u'LAST_NAME')
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=33L, db_column=u'USER_PASSWORD', default="blank")

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'USER'

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.first_name and self.last_name:
            name = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
        else:
            name = self.first_name
        return name
```

If there's anything else to know please ask....

**Update**
I was about to make it work by adding 
`user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` before login. But I still don't understand why this happened....

Comment: I see that you are using a mix of `USER` and `User` in your `authenticate()`. Is it intentional?

Comment: Are you using a custom login method? and/or are you using specifying a custom ModelBackend rather than the default?

Comment: Andea Corbellini: Yes that is intentional. The old application used USER database for authentication and I use the django User model for authentication.

Comment: Richard Price: No I am not using a custom login method and I am specifying a custom authentication backend.

Comment: @memnonila: but what is the problem here exactly? Is the session cookie set? Is the session record in the database? Is the cookie/record stored and then lost at some point?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: The problem is that the login view is called correctly and the user is logged in. Then the user is redirected to another view and the request.user becomes AnonymousUser. Now when I specify the user backend before the login(request, user) it works fine. Also I am new to django so I don't know much. How do you look for the session record in the database and how to know if the session is set or not?

Comment: @memnonila: to check for the cookie you have to look in your browser (it's called `sessionid` by default). To inspect session records, you have to use the [`SessionStore`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views) model. In theory, you should have a `SessionStore` record with a `session_key` that matches the `sessionid` cookie.

Comment: @memnonila: maybe try printing `request.COOKIES` and `SessionStore.objects.all()` before and after logging in, and in other problematic views too.